# org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Ungültige Anmeldedaten

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot

I do my frist Spring app. After start the application, I do a POST and get the described exception. My **SecurityConfig** class looks like:

```
package com.inn.cafe.JWT;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    CustomerUsersDetailsService customerUsersDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    JwtFilter filter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // disabling csrf since we won't use form login
                .csrf().disable()
                // giving permission to every request for /login endpoint
                .authorizeRequests().requestMatchers("/user/login", "/user/signup", "/user/forgotPassword").permitAll()
                // for everything else, the user has to be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                // setting stateless session, because we choose to implement Rest API
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

My **UserService** interface:

```
package com.inn.cafe.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import com.inn.cafe.wrapper.UserWrapper;

public interface UserService {

    ResponseEntity<String> signup(Map<String, String> requestMap);
    
    ResponseEntity<String> login(Map<String, String> requestMap);
    
    ResponseEntity<List<UserWrapper>> getAllUser();
}
```

And my **UserRestImpl** class

```
package com.inn.cafe.restImpl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.inn.cafe.constents.CafeConstants;
import com.inn.cafe.rest.UserRest;
import com.inn.cafe.service.UserService;
import com.inn.cafe.utils.CafeUtils;
import com.inn.cafe.wrapper.UserWrapper;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@RestController
public class UserRestImpl implements UserRest {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> signup(Map<String, String> requestMap) {
        try {
            userService.signup(requestMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity(CafeConstants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(Map<String, String> requestMap) {
        try {
            return userService.login(requestMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity(CafeConstants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserWrapper>> getAllUsers() {
        try {
            return userService.getAllUser();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("{}", "getAllUsers()", e.getMessage());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<UserWrapper>>(new ArrayList<>(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

How do I have to change this class so that the authenticatio not failed?

I have found this article: [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) but this did not work, But I don't know why. Please help me